# How to use substring of a variable in a param or another variable?

Tags: postman

I can use

```
{{guid}}
```

to get an id for body params that I can use for a new records ID.
How do I use a substring of `guid` in postman either in that param variable (which is collection level, by the way) or through another variable?

I tried various such as

```
{{$guid.substring(10)}}
{{$guid}.substring(10)}
```

but they did not work

[image]

I tried to use a pre-request script like this:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("short_guid", pm.collectionVariables.get("myGUID").substr(12) )
```

using my collection variable myGUID which is defined as {{guid}}

along with

```
    "email": "{{$pm.collectionVariables.get('myGUID')}}@example.com",
```

but it does not work as the variable is not interpreted and I get a string literal

Comment: Have you seen something that's made you think you *should* be able to run arbitrary JS in those placeholders? I'd expect that to require a pre-request script.

Comment: A pre-request script looks like a good approach.  I will look into that

Comment: Trying it but not getting it to work so far (info added above).

Comment: Using the pre-request script to create the value you need for the requests, is the only way you could achieve that. This should set the collection variable as that dynamic guid value - `pm.collectionVariables.set("short_guid", pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$guid}}"))` You should be able to use the `{{short_guid}}` variable, in the request body. That doesn't give you the substr but hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: In your screenshot, you're using `guid`, but in the code snippets it's `myGUID`. Might that be the issue? Inconsistent namings?

Comment: It's because of variable Scope , if you have same variable name in collection and environment then value from environment will be taken

Comment: Pm.variables.set should work as it has higher scope

Comment: Hi Could you accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to refer variable in body as {{<variablename}} don't need to call pm.varaible.get

for prerequest :

```
var uuid =  require("uuid")
var myUUID = uuid.v4(); 

pm.environment.set("myuuid",myUUID.substring(20))

console.log(pm.environment.get("myuuid"))
```

And in body

```
{
    "email": {{myuuid}}
}
```

### you can also use variables in script section as:

```
console.log(pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$guid}}").substring(20))
```

This will first replace {{$guid}} with the postman variable value and then find the substring

you can use it like

```
        console.log(pm.variables.replaceIn("this will print {{variable}} value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The second issue of variable not detecting is because of the variable scope

In postman variable scope is from right to left , but precedence is from left to right as follows:

Local>data>environment>collection>global

So if you have a environment variable and collection varible with same name , the value of that variable will be from environment not collection